# phpdoc_annotation_without_dot setting to not change periods at all

Tags: php-cs-fixer

I can't seem to find the documentation that tells how to set `phpdoc_annotation_without_dot` to have it not alter sentences in docblocks. If you set it to `false`, it still adds periods to certain lines. This behavior is unwanted and results in additional work to remove the erroneous periods. What is the setting for `phpdoc_annotation_without_dot` that has it not do anything at all?